# Laravel корзина, какие отношения использовать(полиморфные или обычные)?

Tags: laravel

При разработке интернет магазина, возник вопрос? Если у тебя есть 3 модели Велосипеды, Снаряжение и Аксессуары и я хочу добавить их всех в одну корзину то какие связи следует использовать?

На данный момент создаю под каждую модель реализую свою корзину, а в заказ все потом обьединяю.

Возможно ли данный процесс оптимизировать с помощью полиморфных связей,к примеру Many To Many (Polymorphic) ?

Comment: Как минимум, странно, что у Вас 3 разные таблицы отвечают за товары вместо одной с категорийностью...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По хорошему вас должна быть модель от которой будут наследоваться три ваших типа товара. Назовем её `Product`. Соответственно связь Корзины с Товаром будет просто 1 ко многим.